# npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency npm WARN While resolving: react-headroom@3.0.0

Tags: reactjs

Don't know why the error showing. Please help

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: react-headroom@3.0.0